# "wrench" is to "works" as "crimp" is to what?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

It's commonly said that one [***puts or throws a "[monkey] wrench/(BrEng) spanner" in the "works"***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+a+wrench+in+the+works), but what does one put a "crimp" into?

> CRIMP [Google Image](https://www.google.fr/search?q=monkey+wrench+in+the+works&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=niv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikmOypkMrMAhVJLcAKHfsrACcQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=crimp)
>
> 1. the act of crimping.
> 2. a crimped condition or form.
> 3. Usually **crimps**. waves or curls, especially in hair that has been crimped.
> 4. the waviness of a fiber, either natural, as in sheep wool, or produced by weaving, plaiting, or other processes.
> 5. a crease formed in sheet metal or plate metal to make the material less flexible or for fastening purposes.
>
> **Idioms**
>
> 6. (*chiefly US*) **put a crimp in**: to interfere with; hinder: *His broken leg put a crimp in their vacation plans.*
>
> (Random House)
>
> **put a crimp in** *noun phrase*
>
> To thwart or hamper; block or interfere with; stymie: *How can we put a crimp in this guy's plans?*
>
> [1896+; from the notion of **a severe pinching-in as an obstacle**] (emphasis mine.)
>
> *crimp* *noun*
>
> A restriction; obstacle : *He kept putting crimps into my plan*
>
> *verb*
>
> : *I'll crimp him good with this nasty new rule* (1896+)
>
> (The Dictionary of American Slang)
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/put--a--crimp--in)

Since one can also [put/throw a wrench in someone's plans](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=1024&bih=672&tbm=bks&q=%22a+wrench+in+their+plans%22&oq=%22a+wrench+in+their+plans%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...10226.13956.0.14886.11.11.0.0.0.0.297.1275.0j3j3.6.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..5.2.446...30i10.5opCxEBLYtg), I'm looking for another word than "plans," a word analogous with [**works**](https://www.google.fr/search?q=monkey+wrench+in+the+works&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=niv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikmOypkMrMAhVJLcAKHfsrACcQ_AUIBygC). This doesn't necessarily have to be idiomatic.

> WORKS
>
> (*Mechanical Engineering*) the interior parts of the mechanism of a machine, etc. *the works of a clock*.
>
> Source: Collins English Dictionary

Please, consider the following examples:

> *We were hoping to get the project started in June but the funding was withdrawn so that rather **threw a spanner in the works**.*
>
> *We were hoping to get the project started in June but the funding was withdrawn so that rather **put a crimp in the [word]**.*

-and-

> *The sudden withdrawal of the guest speaker really **threw a monkey wrench in the works**.*
>
> *The sudden withdrawal of the guest speaker really **put a crimp in the [word]**.*

[Source: Cambridge Advanced Learners' Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/throw-a-monkey-wrench-in-the-works)

Comment: We don't throw a *wrench* but a *spanner* in the works. I've never heard of a *crimp* into anything, but occasionally there is a *fly in the ointment* (I believe the latter from the AV bible).

Comment: I am afraid your question is sort of "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @Josh61  By analogy with "put a wrench/spanner in the works, what would you put a crimp https://www.google.fr/search?q=monkey+wrench+in+the+works&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=niv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikmOypkMrMAhVJLcAKHfsrACcQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=crimp into?

Comment: I think you need to consider the two set phrases, the first includes "works" in its form, the second has no specific idiomatic term to be used with.

Comment: ...put a crimp in the conference, in the schedule, in the organisation etc.

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks for your suggestions, Josh, but I'm looking for something figurative, sort of in the same vein as "works" in "throw a wrench in the works" or "chink" in "chink in the armor."

Comment: I believe the simple question is, "How did **crimp** get its figurative meaning of 'disruption, obstacle'?

Comment: Someone crimps your **style**.

Comment: Hot Licks has it. *Put a crimp in S.O.'s style* is also current idiom. And @WS2, what BrE calls a *spanner* AmE calls a *wrench;* but I agree, the overall idiom is so BrE that *wrench* does seem a misfit there.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Does "put a crimp in/crimp s.o.'s style" mean the same as "put a spanner/wrench in s.o.'s works"?

Comment: @WS2 - It's a **monkey** wrench that's thrown into the works.  (Or a wooden shoe, of course.)

Comment: @Elian I think one *throws* the spanner into the works, and that it is less often the case that the *works* belong to one single individual than that the *style* does. To put a crimp in my style is to interfere with my attempt to present myself in a particular, flattering light. Oddly, the idiom with *crimp* is almost entirely interchangeable with one with *cramp,* as in "Get lost, you're cramping my style."

Comment: @BrianDonovan Thing is, I'm looking for a word that, if you literally put a crimp in (or "on") it, might cause a plan or activity to get disrupted.

Comment: *tubing* and *hoses* can be crimped causing a decrease in the inside diameter and this a reduction in the flow rate for a given pressure.

Comment: @BrianDonovan And the Japanese say *supanner*, and from what I remember they also have a similar metaphor about throwing one in the works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Crimp](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/crimp_2)*** is a generic term when used in the following idiomatic expression:.

(Idioms)

> - ***put a crimp in/on something***: 
>     (North American English, informal) to have a bad or negative effect on something
>
>   - *I’m sorry to put a crimp in your plans.

(OLD)

***[Crimp](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crimp)***:

> - 1863, from crimp (v.). ***Originally "natural curl in wool fiber."*** To put a crimp in (something) is 1896, U.S. slang.

Usage examples:

> - The objective of this mission is to put a crimp in the way people move drugs into the United States.
>     Clancy, Tom CLear and present danger (1989)
> - Power cuts are threatening to put a crimp in Christmas.

Comment: Here's am earlier attestation (1879) of the slang meaning   https://books.google.com/books?id=OpMtAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA346&dq=%22put+a+crimp%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxip6kssrMAhXEdD4KHbT3DoEQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22put%20a%20crimp%22&f=false.

Comment: @Tim Romano - good finding.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a sense of [choke](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/choke) suggested by your  "*[1896+; from the notion of a severe pinching-in as an obstacle]"* and the idea of both crimping a pipe (to reduce flow) and crimping a spade lug to a wire that might fit?

A spanner in the works suggests a grinding halt where a crimp is more likely to slow but not stop proceedings.

Answer (score -1):

How about

> put a crimp in his campaign
>   put a crimp in the good cause
>   put a crimp in his crusade